# Validation in custom helper, null reference

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, html-helper

I am creating custom helper for to render a label, the corresponding text box, a validation helper and a surrounding li element.

when i want to include validation message i get an exception :

> System.NullReferenceException: Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.

and have found that it the code failed on: htmlHelper.ValidationMessageFor(expression).ToString();

My Questions:

1. How can I find out specifically which object is null?
2. Is there better way of doing this?

> ```
> public static string MooseTextBoxLineFor<TModel,
> ```
>
> TProperty>(this HtmlHelper
>   htmlHelper, Expression> expression)
>       {
>
> ```
>   TagBuilder liBuilder = new TagBuilder("li");
>   liBuilder.AddCssClass("TextBox");
>
>   liBuilder.InnerHtml = htmlHelper.LabelFor(expression).ToString()
>                             + htmlHelper.EditorFor(expression).ToString()
>                             + htmlHelper.ValidationMessageFor(expression).ToString();
>
>   return liBuilder.ToString();
> }
> ```

Comment: Can you debug the code and put a breakpoint on line where you are doing the ToString()... I suspect one of the lable/editor./validationmessage is null and you are calling the tostring on...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is no validation message then the helper will return null, you are calling ToString() on a null which is why you are getting this error.

Personally I would do this using the EditorTemplates system in MVC but if you'd prefer to do it this way I would do something like:

```
var Label = htmlHelper.LabelFor(expression);
var Editor = htmlHelper.EditorFor(expression);
var Validation = htmlHelper.ValidationMessageFor(expression);

liBuilder.InnerHtml = (Label == null ? "" : Label.ToString())
                                + (Editor == null ? "" : Editor.ToString())
                                + (Validation == null ? "" : Validation.ToString());
```

Comment: I didn't quite get that this was necessary when there was no error being displayed on the screen.  I was like "I have an error message defined for this field" but that wasn't the issue.  Helped me out thanks :)